# printing the contents of list in java

Tags: javascript, string, list, substring

Trying write javascript that prints "username=john01" and "password=password123" from the url below. Currently it prints nothing...

### index.html?username=john01&password=password123&lt=_c1F9F2B16-96B3-9D7B-CC19-D22A43D4FCA1_kA54D6D0E-881B-2792-22D3-B857150B1EFC&_eventId=submit&submit=Sign+In

```
<html>
<body>
<p> This code is for educational purposes only, and is not to be used with malicious intent. </p>
<script>
  string = window.location.search;
  content = string.split("");
  usernameStart = 1;
  usernameEnd = content.indexOf("&",0);
  username = content.substring(usernameStart,usernameEnd));
  document.write("Your username is " + username);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: FYI Java and JavaScript are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var url = 'index.html?username=john01&password=password123&lt=_c1F9F2B16-96B3-9D7B-CC19-D22A43D4FCA1_kA54D6D0E';

var username = url.match(/username=([^&]*)/)[1];
var password = url.match(/password=([^&]*)/)[1];

document.getElementById('userinfo').innerHTML = 'Your username is ' + username + '<br/>And your password is ' + password;
```

You can try it directly on my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qzkdwnub/)

If you replace 'url' with 'window.location' and remove the first line, it should work from the url.